# How to update a label each time in for loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a WinForm project where I have a label in a `for` loop. I want to show the label each time after executing the `label.text` statement. But it doesn't show for every time, rather it shows after for loop is finished.

I tried to achieve this by using `Thread.Sleep()`. But I can't. Please help me. 
 NOTE :- lblProgress is a Label

Here's my coding.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= sourceTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{

    string checkout;
    checkout= sourceTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(0);

    dest = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["local"].ConnectionString);
    dest.Open();
    destcmd = new SqlCommand(checkout, dest);
    destcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dest.Close();

    prcmail();
    prcmessagecheck();


    lblProgress.Text = "Hello World"+i;

    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: Do your work in a background worker and report `i` in the ReportProgress event.

Comment: inside for loop place your label ex:( label.text ="yourtext")

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  , Leave the Progrees bar .. I want show to my Label for every loop .. am getting after for loop finished. Give any solution please. Thank you

Comment: @Senthilkumar  .hi, i did as u say . But i get the label after finishing the for loop

Comment: does DoEvents no longer work? It has been so long since I did a winForm application - do people still use that?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977702/is-application-doevents-just-for-winforms

Comment: to increase thread sleep time to check

Comment: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you create a WinForm application, it is spun up into a new process and a new thread is created. Any updates to the User Interface are all done on the same thread as your process. This means when your application is doing "busy work", your UI will be blocked because they are on the same thread. What this means is that, in order to achieve what it is you're trying to achieve, you have to do a little extra work.

First step we need to do is create a function for your work routine (we could use an anonymous function, but since you are new to C#, I think it'll be easier to understand if we break it out), like this:

```
private void DoWork()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= sourceTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {

        string checkout;
        checkout= sourceTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(0);

        dest = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["local"].ConnectionString);
        dest.Open();
        destcmd = new SqlCommand(checkout, dest);
        destcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dest.Close();

        prcmail();
        prcmessagecheck();


        lblProgress.Text = "Hello World"+i;

        Thread.Sleep(1000); // I changed this from 10000 to 1000 (10 seconds down to 1 second)
    }
}
```

Next, we need to create a new thread that executes our `DoWork()` function. Its unclear what the "trigger" is for doing your work, but I'm going to assume its a button click:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var work = new Thread(DoWork);
    work.Start();
}
```

So now, whenever someone click the button, we will start a new thread that executes our `DoWork` function in that thread. The new thread spawns, then execution is immediate returned and our GUI will now update in real time as our thread is executing in the background.

But wait! We still have one more problem to take care of. The problem is that Window's form controls are not thread safe and if we try to update a control from another thread, other then the GUI's thread, we will get a cross-thread operation error. The key to fixing this is to use `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke`.

First, we need to make another function that does just the label update:

```
private void SetProgressLabel(int progress)
{
    lblProgress.Text = "Hello World" + progress;
}
```

In your form class, we also need to create a new delegate:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private delegate void ProgressCallback(int progress);

    // ..
    // The rest of your code
    // ..
}
```

Finally, change your `DoWork()` method to something like this:

```
private void DoWork()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= sourceTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {

        string checkout;
        checkout= sourceTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(0);

        dest = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["local"].ConnectionString);
        dest.Open();
        destcmd = new SqlCommand(checkout, dest);
        destcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dest.Close();

        prcmail();
        prcmessagecheck();


        if (lblProgress.InvokeRequired)
        {
            lblProgress.Invoke(new ProgressCallback(SetProgressLabel), new object[] { i });
        }
        else
        {
            SetProgressLabel(i);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000); // I changed this from 10000 to 1000 (10 seconds down to 1 second)
    }
}
```

This uses the label's (derived from `Control`) `InvokeRequired` property to determine if an `Invoke` is required. It returns `true` or `false`. If its `false`, we can just call our `SetProgressLabel()` function like we'd normally do. If its `true`, we must use `Invoke` to call our function instead.

Congratulations! You just made your first thread safe application.

Now, just as an aside note, you are not properly releasing and disposing of your objects. I recommend you change your `DoWork()` code to something like this:

```
private void DoWork()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= sourceTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        string checkout;
        checkout = sourceTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(0);

        using (dest = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["local"].ConnectionString))
        {
            dest.Open();
            using (destcmd = new SqlCommand(checkout, dest))
            {
                destcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dest.Close();

                prcmail();
                prcmessagecheck();

                if (lblProgress.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    lblProgress.Invoke(new ProgressCallback(SetProgressLabel), new object[] { i });
                }
                else
                {
                    SetProgressLabel(i);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000); // I changed this from 10000 to 1000 (10 seconds down to 1 second)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because I wrapped your `IDisposable`'s into `using` blocks, the resources will automatically be disposed of once it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

Although threading would be the more ideal solution another solution is:

Application.DoEvents()

this will give the UI thread time to update.

Example

```
for (int i = 1; i <= sourceTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{

string checkout;
checkout= sourceTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(0);

dest = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["local"].ConnectionString);
dest.Open();
destcmd = new SqlCommand(checkout, dest);
destcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
dest.Close();

prcmail();
prcmessagecheck();


lblProgress.Text = "Hello World"+i;

Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: Although this sometimes works, `DoEvents` is asynchronous which means it terminates before the application has actually processed any outstanding events, so if you're using it in a procedure with many sequential statements, calling `DoEvents` causes a huge disturbance whenever it's called. Basically, if you find yourself needing to call `DoEvents` anywhere, think about starting another thread instead, or using asynchronous delegates.

Comment: I accept its not an elegant approach and threading is the more idea l, however for the scope of the question was trying to offer a simple solution. The author of the question is new to coding and the "DoEvents()" is maybe a beginners approach, and hopefully they will refactor at a later date to include a worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= sourceTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                        string checkout;
                        checkout = sourceTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(0);

                        dest = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["local"].ConnectionString);
                        dest.Open();
                        destcmd = new SqlCommand(checkout, dest);
                        destcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        dest.Close();

                        prcmail();
                        prcmessagecheck();

                    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {      
                         //Thread.Sleep(1000);

                        lblProgress.Text = "Hello World" + i;

                    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, ui);

                    task.Wait();

                }
            });
```

Comment: This is still going to lock up the UI for 1000 ms intervals because you do a `Thread.Sleep` on the UI tread.

Comment: But why put it in the UI thread, put it before the `task` then just pass the value of `i` at the end (btw, you might have issues with variable captures, you may want to declare a new variable inside the for loop and use that inside the anonymous delegate.)

Comment: actually looking at it again it won't work, you will have the wrong value of `i` for `sourceTable.Rows[i].Field<string>(0);` They are all likely to point at the last or near to last row due to `i` having the wrong value, you need to do a `var j = i;` inside the for loop and use `j` inside the anonomous delegate.

Comment: You are still missing the issue to fix the [variable capture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp). (The `var j = i;` then using `lblProgress.Text = "Hello World" + j;`)

Comment: I understood your point but it's working in VS 2013 without assigning to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing the mentioned code on the UI thread, UI will be refreshed only after entire for loop is executed. Based on your needs, progress bar/background worker kind of set up looks suitable.

Comment: can u give any example coding to achieve my o/p ? Am new to programming. so please help me